# One component ngOnInit hook is called from other component route

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-module

I have one root module with two feature module. And i will load the first feature module with route /one. And in that /one routes components ngOnInit() lifecycle hook i am opening one modal. And that will be closed before filling the form.

And then i route to /two routes component, but in this component ngOnInit() hook i don't have any modal to open, but still the same modal which i opened in /one is getting opened.

Any idea why /one ngOnInit() hook is invoked while routing to /two ngOnInit() hook?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please?

Comment: are you closing modal before route change or for example you have button in modal that when you click it route is changed?

Comment: @MehranBeiglou : As soon as, i open /one modal will appear. From there, i will close the modal first (its just information modal), after completing /one form i will click next button to load the /two, but some how that /one ngOnInit hook is getting called again in /two route component.

Comment: I think you have problem in a other place can you share your code in stackblitz or stuff?